# Stuck on science cap

Tags: kittens-game

I am stuck and can't get my science up anymore.

My science max is 388.254K
I have
60 academies (next upgrade is at 438K science)
63 Observatories (Next upgrade is at 405K science)
59 Biolabs (Next upgrade is at 415K science)
15 Satelites (Next upgrade is at 396K science)
9 Space stations (Next upgrade is at 415K science)

And I do not posses more science to upgrade. Is the only legitimate way for me to increase my wood cap and try to build more libraries? I am 91 libraries and next one requires 8.345M wood and my wood cap is only 8.087 and hard to increase higher.

How does one increase their science cap? I understand that after 250k there is no need for science, but I want to pool it overnight and use it to make blueprints.

EDIT:

Forgot to mention I also have
Scholasticism at level 6 (next level is at 61k faith)
And Transcendence is researched.

Comment: Keep building Temples is about all you can do at that point ^_^ unless you're maxed on them too.  However, I've found trading works a lot better for blueprint production than crafting them yourself.

Answer (score 12):

Get Transcendence and put some points to Scholasticism, tat will help you to squeeze a bit from Temples.

Compendiums provide a bit of max science. The bonus may be laughable, but don't underestimate it.

But realistically the only way to get decent science cap at this point would be to wait for unobtainium/sattelite upgrades. (Folks, for the holy living mother of unicorn, don't ask me why I think there would be unobtainium/science upgrades. I just know).

Comment: Thanks :) I posted an update in regards to your answer. Looking forward to your updates blood. Science is stuck for me for now.