# Why do some of my maximums sometimes decrease?

Tags: kittens-game

I've noticed quite a few times that in [Kittens Game](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/), at seemingly random times, maximums I used to have go down. I have noticed this in conjunction with reloading the page (presumably an update happened), but I've also noticed it without reloading the page.

Most recently I noticed that  my oil maximum went down to about 45K, but this is *after* I've already made a lunar outpost, which requires 50K (so .. at least I'm sane).

Can the game reload itself automatically for updates? Are there certain things that trigger maximums on certain resources to decrease? What could be happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is certainly possible for storage capacity to decrease.  For example, [compendiums provide a small boost to max science](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/190691/stuck-on-science-cap/190697#190697), so if you craft blueprints from your compendiums, you will see a decrease in max science.

I'm not aware of anything like that specific to oil...however, there is paragon, which [boosts overall storage capacity](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=paragon&redirect=no), so you could arrive at the situation you describe by spending paragon points on Metaphysics...

---

Update: Another possibility to consider...your total storage capacity can decrease from crafting Tankers.  This is because crafting Tankers consumes Ships, and Ships (with upgrades) provide a bonus multiplier to Harbour capacity.

Comment: Oh i see. That must be it. I definitely have spent some paragon